# Comparing partitions of a table and creating index for unique partition in TSQL (if it's possible)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a simple task to do. Though it may be impossible to do using TSQL.

I want to compare partitions of SQL table basing on sequence of elements (for example stops sequence of bus route). Here is my table:

```
ID  BusNr     Seq     StopName   Date       
1   789        1         A     2015-04-08
2   789        2         B     2015-04-08
3   789        3         C     2015-04-08
4   789        4         D     2015-04-08
5   789        1         A     2015-04-16
6   789        2         B     2015-04-16
7   789        3         D     2015-04-16
8   789        1         A     2015-05-10
9   789        2         B     2015-05-10
10  789        3         C     2015-05-10
11  789        4         D     2015-05-10
12  789        5         E     2015-05-10
```

The sample shows one bus line which takes different routes in three different dates. The route is given by stop sequences. What I need is to find a way to refer to stop sequence of a route and find for every bus line unique stop sequences. Then I would like to create a table of unique stop sequences (with index for each one) which I could connect to the table above.

Is it possible to perform a join based on identity of such sequences ?

Please give me any advices to solve my problem. I am wondering if I could use window functions, but at this moment I didn't find a solution.

Comment: This really looks like you're solving the wrong problem at the wrong time. Shouldn't you be doing this when a new stop sequence is being put in, rather than on huge amounts of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Too little rep to comment]
I'd like to help, but am unclear with your objective.
I get this:
A route is a unique list of stops.
Different days have different routes.
I want the distinct routes per busline.

```
Maybe you want this:
1. 789 ABC, 
2. 789 ABD, 
3. 789 ABCDE
```

You would need another piece of information to make this unique when joining as 3 possible matches on BusLine exist, to tie back with the date... something you can compute like 1st week, 2cnd week, ... do you agree?

If so, you need to decide if you want to use the 1 row per route, or split it out into:

```
 PK INT, BusNr INT, RouteStopSeq INT, RouteStopName CHAR, RouteWeekNumber INT
 1, 789, 1, A, 1
 2, 789, 2, B, 1
 3, 789, 3, C, 1
 4, 789, 1, A, 2
 5, 789, 2, B, 2
 6, 789, 3, D, 2
 ...
```

SO... each day having a different route makes the table you want to create the same as the data you provide... difficult to see the overall pattern from such a small set.

```
    CREATE TABLE TempDB.dbo.Data 
   (
   ID INT,
   BusNr INT,
   Seq INT,
   StopName CHAR(1),
   Date DATETIME       
   )
   INSERT INTO TempDB.dbo.Data VALUES
   ( 1,789,1,'A','2015-04-08'),
   ( 2,789,2,'B','2015-04-08'),
   ( 3,789,3,'C','2015-04-08'),
   ( 4,789,4,'D','2015-04-08'),
   ( 5,789,1,'A','2015-04-16'),
   ( 6,789,2,'B','2015-04-16'),
   ( 7,789,3,'D','2015-04-16'),
   ( 8,789,1,'A','2015-05-10'),
   ( 9,789,2,'B','2015-05-10'),
   (10,789,3,'C','2015-05-10'),
   (11,789,4,'D','2015-05-10'),
   (12,789,5,'E','2015-05-10')

   CREATE FUNCTION fnConcatenateStopNames (@BusNr INT, @Date DATETIME)
   RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
   AS 
   BEGIN
DECLARE @RouteStopList VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @RouteStopList = @RouteStopList + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),StopName)
FROM TempDB.dbo.Data D
WHERE D.BusNr = @BusNr
AND D.Date = @Date
ORDER BY Seq

RETURN STUFF(@RouteStopList,1,1,'')
  END

   SELECT BusNr, Stops, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BusNr, Stops) BusRouteNumber
   FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT D.BusNr, dbo.fnConcatenateStopNames (D.BusNr, D.Date) Stops 
FROM TempDB.dbo.Data D
   ) Data
```

EDIT: Using the information supplied...
Using the function I supplied, against your full set, will resolve a string of stops, busnr, and date... aggregating your pathdata into a route count.

Using the route count against sum of all routes, you can determine the ratio of routes per bus.

If you use this against the routelist I posted as my last statement, you could possibly extrapolate back to the most frequently service stops too :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wasn't sure if I could refer to a sequence in TSQL, that's why I haven't yet thought about further aggregation. The  purpose of this task is to find for every bus most frequent routes (for example - routes that occur more than 50% of runs in a year) . In fact the routes are repeating during a year, and there is no more than 3 different routes in some more complicated cases. But I need to somehow aggregate them - in ideal situation I would like a table with two added columns - one with ID of stop sequence set and second with ID of running dates set.